# switch my camera follow from my character to another object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a script in my camera that follow my main character, this is the script :

```
public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform target; // this is my player

    public float smoothing;

    Vector3 offset;
    float lowy;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        offset = transform.position - target.position;
        lowy = transform.position.y;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {
        Vector3 targetcampos = target.position + offset;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetcampos, smoothing * Time.deltaTime);

    }
}
```

I want to know how my camera follow script switch to an object temporarily (my object is a rolling rock) . I plan this to occur when my object (rock) enters another collider2d of an object  and  return the follow behavior to my character after a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing: When rock enters the collider, the collider set the camera target to another transform.

**Script on your empty trigger collider**

```
CameraFollow m_MainCamera;

void Start()
{
    m_MainCamera = Camera.main.GetComponent<CameraFollow>();    
}

OnTriggerEnter(collider coll)
{
    if(coll.gameObject.tag == "rock")
    {
        m_MainCamera.SwapTargetTo(coll.transform);
    }       
}
```

*Note: Remember to give a tag to the rock!*

**Now updates your camera script to looks like:**

```
public Transform player;
public Transform target;

void Start()
{
    target = player;
}

void SwapTargetTo(Transform newTarget)
{
    target = newTarget;
}
```

You can make the target to swap when enters to another empty collider, doing the same thing, or making a Coroutine to check time, is up to you!

Edit: If you want fancy stuff, try CameraMachine! :D

Comment: CameraMachine?  Or CineMachine?